# For online payments, how to create invoice for each product separately

Tags: invoice, partial-invoice

I have different vendors for each product in my magento store. When I receive an order, I need to create individual invoices for each product in the order so that the invoice can be sent to that product's vendor. Please help in achieving that. At present, magento auto generates one single invoice for the whole order since payment is online using a third party payment module.

Answer (score 0):

Your payment method should allow you to choose an action: Authorize, or Authorize and Capture (or Sale, or Order). Authorize and Capture means the entire order is automatically invoiced at checkout.

Change the payment action to Authorize, and then you should be able to manually invoice each item separately.

If Authorize is not an option, or your payment method does not have any Payment Action setting, try contacting the creator of that payment method, or look for alternatives.

You will also need to make sure the payment method actually supports partial invoicing. Many do not.

Comment: My payment module does have option of authorize or authorize and capture. However, even the authorize only option does not let me invoice partially. The authorize only option shows an invoice button in orders but it does not let me change qty of individual products so that I can invoice only  particular items in the order by making others 0 and that way make multiple invoices.

Comment: @Pranjal okay, you need a new payment method that supports that then.